# PyOpenSSL: Force SSL negotiations without sending/receiving?

Tags: python, pyopenssl

Is it possible to force PyOpenSSL into performing the SSL negotiation (and, specifically, retrieving the peer's certificate) without trying to send/receive data?

Currently, with this code:

```
    ssl_soc = SSL.Connection(self._mk_ctx(), plain_soc)
    ssl_soc.set_connect_state()
    cert = ssl_soc.get_peer_certificate()
```

The call to `get_peer_certificate` returns `None`, but once I've called, eg, `ssl_soc.write("hello")`, `get_peer_certificate` starts returning the certificate like I'd expect.

Comment: Oh man! I couldn't even figure that it returned `None` only before any send/receive. In retrospect, it should have been obvious since I also used `VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT` flag and it didn't fail. Realized only after seeing this question.

Answer (score 3):

Err, clearly I need to RTFM a little harder. I was looking for the `do_handshake` method: http://packages.python.org/pyOpenSSL/openssl-connection.html